# Angular Filter array with only 1 object with the value true

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

I want to filter this object

```
var tabledata = [
    0: {Email: "user1@test.com", APP1: true, APP2: false, APP3: false, APP4: true}
]
```

i want only the value EMAIL and TRUE visible like this.

```
var tabledata = [
    0: {"Email":"user1@test.com","APP1":true,"APP4":true}
]
```

or like this

```
var tabledata = {"Email":"user1@test.com","APP1":true,"APP4":true}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remap your `tabledata` like that:

```js
let tabledata = [
    {Email: "user1@test.com", APP1: true, APP2: false, APP3: false, APP4: true},
    {Email: "abc@you.com", APP1: false, APP2: false, APP3: true, APP4: false},
];


let result = tabledata.map((item) => {
    let dict = {};
    for (key in item) {
        if (item[key]) {
            dict[key] = item[key] 
        }
    }
    return dict;
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do like this.**

```
var tabledata-2 = {}

for (key : tabledata[0].keys()) {
    if (key === 'Email' || tabledata[0][key]) {
       tabledata-2[key] = tabledata[0][key];
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, i need to filter on value true not on the key.

Comment: Ok I have edited now only true values will be in tablevalue_2

Comment: Also should "Email" be always in the filtered object?

Comment: Okay above I have edited accordingly...It should be fine

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid syntax in JavaScript:

```
var tabledata = [
    0: {Email: "user1@test.com", APP1: true, APP2: false, APP3: false, APP4: true}
]
```

I assume you mean that tabledata is an object:

```
var tabledata = {
    0: {Email: "user1@test.com", APP1: true, APP2: false, APP3: false, APP4: true}
}
```

Also JavaScript wise it doesn't make a difference if you write:

```
{"Email": "..."}
```

or

```
{Email: "..."}
```

as long as the object key does not contain special characters.

If you want to map your object in a functional way, you use reduce and map:

```
Object.values(tabledata).map(entry => {
  // Remove values that are false.
  const filteredProperties = Object.entries(entry)
    .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => value !== false ? [...acc, [key, value]] : acc, []);
  return Object.fromEntries(filteredProperties);
})
```

This would then give you:

```
[
  {Email: "user1@test.com", APP1: true, APP4: true}
]
```

If tabledata is an array, the job is a bit simpler btw (I'm not sure from your post if tabledata really is an object, or if you copied the line from the console):

```
tabledata.map(entry => {
  const filteredProperties = Object.entries(entry)
    .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => value !== false ? [...acc, [key, value]] : acc, []);
  return Object.fromEntries(filteredProperties);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work to.

```
var tabledata_2 = {}
let objects = Object.values(tabledata)                      
    for(var i=0; i<objects.length; i++) {
       for(var key in objects[i]) {               
       if (!!objects[i][key]) {
       tabledata_2[key] = tabledata[0][key];
       }
     }
    console.log(tabledata_2) 
    }
```